# Why is it possible to delete an uninitialized pointer in a destructor, but not in main?

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor, delete-operator

please check the destructor of the foo function below. If I delete the p pointer then it runs fine. But if I do the same in main program then I get an error. Why does it allow me to do this in a destructor?

P.S. I know that there's no point in deleting the pointer because there is no dynamically allocated memory.

```
class foo
{
  int* p;

public:
  ~foo()
  {
    delete p; // runs fine
    cout << "Destructor run \n";
  }
};


int main()
{

int* p;
delete p; // This will cause error "uninitialized local variable 'p' used "

foo test; // destructor runs fine at the end of the program

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not because you didn't see a problem that it's fine. Both of these cases are undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes indeed, both are wrong. Always initialize your objects.

Comment: Because the compiler didn't detect the Undefined Behavior in the case where it allows it. There is no requirement for a compiler to issue a warning in either case even though they are both wrong.

Comment: *"I know that there's no point in deleting the pointer because there is no dynamically allocated memory."* It's not that there is no point. It's that you are not allowed to `delete` a pointer that doesn't point to something that was `new`ed (with the exception of deleting `nullptr` which doesn't do anything). Though in this case, since the pointers are uninitialized, you can't even get to the point of breaking that rule.

Comment: It doesn't *runs fine*.  It's undefined behavior and you got lucky/unlucky that it didn't crash.

Comment: Deleting a random pointer leads to undefined behavior. Sometimes compilers can see through this and warn you, sometimes they don't.  It is still the problem.

Comment: @Vegeta good question!!! but you did not specifically call destructor.

Comment: The compiler can see that in `main` there is no way that `p` was initialized before `delete p` and can notify you. That's a no-brainer, but because in `foo` `p` is left uninitialized as a member variable and the compiler later could find a constructor or other method that does initialize it, tracking that it's uninitialized is murkier, and would require a fairly large amount of extra work and book keeping that most compilers wouldn't bother with.

Comment: @Gox No need. Destructor call is implied when `test` goes out of scope.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the answer

Comment: I don't think the OP talks about a warning here. Problem an actual crash. My compiler/platform reproes this behaviour. Crash on int pointer delete, but UB "no failure" on the object delete.

Comment: Why all the dislikes though? Is the question not clear?

Comment: I guess not. Made sense to me though. Why does the compiler generate an error for flawed code type 1 but not for flawed code type 2. People fixated on the fact that it was flawed code instead of what you asked. Maybe add a header proclaiming that *I know this is Terrible, Horrible, No Good, Very Bad Code, but the question is "Why does one case generate an error and the other doesn't?"*

Answer (score 8):

In both cases, the pointer in question contains an *indeterminate value*. Accessing that value, even just to read it (never mind passing it to `delete`), causes undefined behaviour. It's not ok when it's a local variable, and it's not ok when it's a class member either. It simply happens that the compiler was clever enough to catch it in the case of the local variable. For the class member, it's harder for the compiler to figure out that nothing in the program can give the pointer a determinate value.

Comment: I think this is the point. The OP is not really clear about compile time vs. run time and is complaining about the differences in compiler diagnostics.

Answer (score 2):

> please check the destructor of the foo function below. If I delete the p pointer then it runs fine. But if I do the same in main program then I get an error. Why does it allow me to do this in a destructor?

It is not that it is allowed in one place and not another.  It is **undefined** behavior** in both cases.

The real issue is just that the compiler DOESN'T KNOW that the `foo::p` member is uninitialized inside the `~foo()` destructor, since the declaration of `p` and the call to `delete p` are in different scopes.  `foo::p` could be assigned anytime after a `foo` object is constructor and before it is destructed.  The compiler CAN'T verify that condition.

Whereas inside of `main()`, the declaration of the local `p` variable and the call to `delete p` are in the same scope, and the compiler can easily see that `p` is never initialized.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from François Andrieux is good:

> It's not because you didn't see a problem that it's fine. Both of these cases are undefined behavior. – François Andrieux 3 mins ago

The reason why it passes, in practice, is that a popular compiler/platform has the dynamic memory (heap) zero'ed out before you allocate from it. So, your *p* happens to be 0, which can be deleted safely. This compiler/platform doesn't do it for stack variables.

EDIT:
A more likely scenario, given the comment, is that the int variable gets put into a register. Which is definitely not initialized to anything meaningfull. But the stack memory, where the object will reside, might (just might) be initialiazed to 0.

But yeah, don't rely on UB.

Comment: Note that the `test` object is _not_ heap-allocated. It's also a stack variable.

Comment: @justin darn good point.